# wso2 esb jms message redelivery

Tags: jms, wso2, activemq-classic, wso2-esb

I have a **WSO2** proxy service that sends a SOAP message to a JMS queue with `OUT_ONLY=true`. The JMS broker is Active MQ.

If the Active MQ service isn't running on the server I find that the messages are stored in ESB until it is started again.

How is this temporary storage configured? Where can I get more information about it?

Answer (score 2):

In WSO2 ESB, there is an In-Memory message store which can be used to store the messages with in the ESB itself.

**In Memory Message Store**

In Memory Message Store is the default Message Store that will be created if user does not specify any implementation from the configuration. Messages will be stored in an in-memory queue. So in case of a ESB restart, all the messages stored will be lost.

In Memory Message Store is lot more faster than any persistence message store implementations. So it can be used as a temporary storage of messages for use cases such as implementation of high speed store and forwarded patterns where message persistence is not a requirement.

http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB460/Message+Stores

Here is another article on message stores.

http://techfeast-hiranya.blogspot.com/2012/01/wso2-esb-tips-tricks-08-message-stores.html

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to set exponential back-off redelivery policy?